# Angular- Pass attribute into directive and use it as a property name on object

Tags: angularjs

How can I use the attribute `checkType` to resolve in such  a manner as `scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp[checkType];`? I am doing this so I can plug in the value and make the directive reusable.

Right now I get `ReferenceError: checkType is not defined`

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.directive("countDown", [ 'sseHandler', function (sseHandler) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            countFrom: "=",
            checkType: "@"
        },
        template :  '<div class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" id="api-time">'+
            'Next update in &nbsp <span class="info-test">{{countFrom}}</span>'+ 
            '&nbsp seconds',

        link: function(scope){
           scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult || "initializing";
           scope.$on('ONE_SEC', function() {
               if (sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult < -3) {
                   scope.countFrom = "Snap! Broadcast is late." +
                                     " Something is broke";
               }
               else if (sseHandler.broadcastStamp.cpuResult <0) {
                   scope.countFrom = "running a little late";
               } else {
                   //THIS IS WHERE I AM TESTING IT AT
                   scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp[checkType];
               }
           });
        }
    }
}]);
```

---

```
<count-down count-from="countDownTicker" check-type="cpuResult"></count-down>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 link: function(scope, element,attr) {
        ...
        scope.countFrom = $parse('sseHandler.broadcastStamp.' + attr.checkType)({sseHandler: sseHandler});
 });
```

Remember to inject $parse into your directive function.

Comment: no luck with `sseHandler.broadcastStamp[attr.checkType]`

Comment: I want to pass in `check-type="cpuResult"` to the directive so I can use it in the manner of `scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp[checkType]` but checkType is undefined.

Comment: I made a horribly dumb mistake...forgot to include function parameters. Thanks!

Comment: I was using function(scope) and not function(scope, element,attr) {}

Answer (score 1):

Before I get into the answer, I shall let you know what is/how is isolated scope works.

There are 3 types of isolated scopes available on `AngularJS` directives.

```
scope: {
    isolated1: '@attribute1',
    isolated2: '=attribute2',
    isolated3: '&attribute3'
}
```

---

**1.  Interpolating the attribute with `@`**

The `@` symbol indicates that `AngularJS` should interpolate the value of the attribute and update the isolated scope property when it changes. Interpolation is used with `{{}}` curly braces to **generate a string using values from the parent scope**.

---

**2.  Binding data to the attribute with `=`**

The `=` symbol indicates that `AngularJS` should keep the expression in the specified attribute and the value on the isolated scope *in sync* with each other. This is **two-way-data-binding** that allows objects and values to be mapped directly between the inside and outside of the `directive`.

---

**3.  Providing a callback expression in the attribute with `&`**

The `&` symbol indicates that the expression provided in the attribute on the element will be made available on the scope as a *function* that, when called, when execute the expression. This is thus useful for creating **callbacks** from the `directive`.

---

For your case, since you are using `@` notation, a common mistake is to expect an interpolated object to be the object itself. **Interpolation always returns a string**.

So if you have an `object`, say user has a filed called `userName`, then the interpolation of `{{user}}` will convert the `user` object to a string and you will not be able to access the `userName` property on the string.

Comment: Still no success with `checkType: "="` or `checkType: "@"`

Comment: what happens if you access `checkType` outside of the `scope.on()`? Do you still get undefined?